# Is it possible to use window.location.reload() on a page to reload all contents but one?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to javaScript & would like to know if is possible to use window.location.reload() on a page to reload all contents on a page but one? I've researched google but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean repull all resources except for one? Can you give a more specific use case, because this seems a very strange request.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no it is not possible to reload the page partially with `window.reload()`

What you could do though is fetched the HTML page and use it to replace partial content on your page. It would be better if your backend could serve already the parts of your page you need individually, so you only have to update the content of the page instead of parsing some HTML first, but it can work both ways.

For example from one sample project I made. This will fetch periodically some HTML from the backend and update the page partially.
You can see the full thing here https://repl.it/@bluebrown/SSR-Dataframes#templates/dashboard.html

```js
const fetcher = Object.entries(frames).map(([id, {refresh_rate}]) => {
    function refresh() {
      fetch(`/df/${id}`)
        .then((bytes) => bytes.text())
        .then((html) => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html)
        .catch(console.warn)
      return setTimeout(refresh, refresh_rate*1000)
    }
    return refresh();
  })
```

This works so well because the backend and the frontend know each other well.
In other cases you may want or need to fetch a full page and parse it with something like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Then you can grab from that DOM what you need and update the right element on your page.

Answer (score 0):

The location.reload method reloads the current document, just like the user pressed F5 or the browser reload button.

The default setting reloads the page from `browser cache`, if it is available. You can force the method to bypass `local cache` and retrieve the document from the network by passing true to the method.

```
location.reload(); //refreshes from cache //or location.reload(true); //to force a network request
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, location.reload will reload the current document. Only way I can think, and this may not work with your page design, you can put the different contents in separate iframes, and reload only those iframes that needs reload/refresh.